# how to change type of object in razor page

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a cshtml file with the folloowing code

```
  @if (Session.CurrentUser == null)
                        {
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Account")</li>
                        }
```

The Session obj comes from this class i've made

```
 public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected Services Services { get; private set; }
        protected new SessionWrapper Session { get { return SessionWrapper.Instance; } }
        protected ConfigWrapper Config { get { return ConfigWrapper.Instance; } }

        public BaseController()
        {
            Services = new Services();
        }
    }
```

so session is SessionWrapper type and it has a CurrentUser property in it.
In my cshtml file, Session is type HttpSessionStateBase
How do I change the type? 
I have tried with SessionWraper.CurrentUser

Comment: Try replacing the variable name, Session -> sessionWrapper, since session is reserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the variable name:

```
protected SessionWrapper sessionWrapper;

public BaseController()
        {
            Services = new Services();
            sessionWrapper = new SessionWrapper.Instance;
        }
```

And the same in the razor page:

```
@if (sessionWrapper.CurrentUser == null)
```

The issue you are getting here is that [Session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.session?view=netframework-4.8) is reserved